# How to apply parent application's layout and assets to mounted engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created an engine for blogging system in my app. This blog engine should be mounted as `/blog` and should have similar appearance (header/footer/css etc.) to the parent app.

How do you apply the parent app's layout and assets to mounted engine?

- Ruby: 2.2.0
- Rails: 4.2.0

Comment: Do you mean the header and footer or the whole layout  ?

Comment: I mean the whole layout which includes header and footer.

Comment: One thing you can do is divide the layouts and then include that in the mounted engine , the same way https://github.com/radar/forem does

Comment: Thanks. I've taken a look at forem and have got it, I'm going to try to implement layout selector like [this](https://github.com/radar/forem/blob/cc6e884c64a0be5aa64647235ff604b42a04a51f/lib/forem.rb#L89) in my engine, and specify it in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply follow the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#using-a-class-provided-by-the-application), which talks about using a class provided by the application.

Comment: Thanks. I've already read this guide, but I cannot find instruction about using application's assets (not classes) in an engine.

Comment: You can use a class, then you should be able to use this to define a parent controller, which decalres the layout you need ;)